# Javascript lazy load images by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I have a page with a very long list of images and I'm looking to lazy load them. But instead of loading the images when they appear in the viewport, I want to load them in order of `id` when the page is ready. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my markup. My goal would be to load realimg1, realimg2, realimg3, etc in order.

```
<img src="loading.png" width="300" height="200" id="id1" data-src="realimg1.png">
<img src="loading.png" width="300" height="200" id="id2" data-src="realimg2.png">
<img src="loading.png" width="300" height="200" id="id3" data-src="realimg3.png">
<img src="loading.png" width="300" height="200" id="id4" data-src="realimg4.png">
<img src="loading.png" width="300" height="200" id="id5" data-src="realimg5.png">
```

Right now, I'm using [this plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) just lazy loading images by replacing the `src` with `data-src` when the image come into the viewport. How would I do the same thing but do it on load in order of `id` instead of when they appear in the viewport?

Comment: So the loading of the images will have nothing to do with being in the viewport? You want the images to load in a sequence based on the id (ie. each image only starts loading after the one before it has finished)?

Comment: @Lebowski156 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will find the lazy loading to be of any use as it's functionality is entirely directed at loading based on images appearing in the viewport.

Check this out:

---

Hi, this demo might be of interest to you

http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/860_preloaderPlugin/index.html

and the corresponding tutorial is here:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-awesome-image-preloader/

it uses a jQuery plugin that is called like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $("#gallery").preloader();

    });

</script>
```

Where

```
<ul id="gallery" class="clearfix">

        <li><p><a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a></p></li>

        <li><p><a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></a></p> </li>

        <li><p><a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></a></p> </li>

        <li><p><a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" /></a></p></li>

        <li><p><a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" /></a></p> </li>

    </ul>
```

source: http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/7959

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function lazyLoader(id){
        var images = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(prop in images){
            images[prop].setAttribute('src', images[prop].getAttribute('data-src')); 
        }
    }
    // should be called after document ready or load - 
    lazyLoader('lazy_loader');

</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy) plugin, which prevents to use external dependencies. It can load by id. You only have to provide the images to load.

For your images you can call the library as follows:

```js
var placeholders = document.querySelectorAll(".some-class-of-images-to-load");
for (var i = 0; i < placeholders.length; ++i) {
    Justlazy.lazyLoad(placeholders[i]);
}
```

The placeholders have to be in the following structure:

```html
<span data-src="default/image" data-alt="some alt text"
      class="some-class-of-images-to-load">
</span>
```

For SEO reasons you can use any other placeholder element.